# JQuery .change - getting source of event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a number of  elements on a HTML forms, similar to the following:

```
<div class="area">
    First Area
    <select class="area_select" name="area_25" id="form_area_25">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">No</option>
        <option value="1" >Don't Mind</option>
        <option value="2" >Yes</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="area">
    Second Area
    <select class="area_select" name="area_13" id="form_area_13">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">No</option>
        <option value="1" >Don't Mind</option>
        <option value="2" >Yes</option>
    </select>
</div>
    .... and many more
```

They all have a class of area_select, and id of form_area_id where id as a unique integer.

I am trying to use jQuery to write an event handler for when the user changes a select box.

All I've managed to get so far is this:

```
$(".area_select").change(function() {
  alert('select changed, but no idea which one');
});
```

Is there any way to let the event handler know exactly which select is the source of the event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` within the even refers to the control that fired the event:

```
$('.area_select').change(function(){
  // this = the control
});
```

Is that what you're going for? Or you can accept `e` in the callback and look at `e.target`.

```
$('.area_select').change(function(e){
  // e.target = the control (unless bubbling occurred)
});
```

Docs on [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

If you wanted to get the ID of the select (just the number) you could use:

```
$(".area_select").change(function() {
    var selectid = this.id.match(/(\d+)$/)[1];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this` for source object and `this.id` for source object `id`.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8vtKA/)**

```
$(".area_select").change(function(event) {
  alert(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `$(this)` to get the control that triggered the event

```
$(".area_select").change(function() {
   alert($(this).attr("id") + " changed");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` is the source.  Indeed, the function you bind to an event is invoked in the context of the item in which the event occurs.  So it's simply:

```
$(".area_select").change(function() {
  alert('select ' + $(this).attr("id") + " changed");
});
```

Comment: You should use [`.prop()` over `.attr()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr), especially if you're going to access native [properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element#Properties). Even better is excluding jQuery altogether and just referencing [`this.id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.id).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `this` :

```
$(".area_select").change(function() {
      alert('select changed: '+$(this).val()+' , but no idea which one: '
      +$(this).attr('id').replace('form_area_',''));
});
```